# Eclipse periodically freezes when editing large project in a git repository

Tags: eclipse, pydev, egit

I am developing a python project in Eclispe 3.7, PyDev, and EGit. Every 20 minutes or so, Eclipse will freeze up, displaying in the bottom-right corner "Git repository refresh Job: (0%)"  Once this number increases above 0%, the UI becomes responsive again and can be used until the next time it freezes. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Whoops... should be 3.7. Editing now

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bug in EGit. Could you write an email to the EGit mailing list (egit-dev@eclipse.org) or file a bug report on http://bugs.eclipse.org and provide as many information as possible?

As a first workaround you could look at the options on Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git and on that page the preference "Refresh resources when index changed" and "Refresh only when workbench is active". You can also look at Label decoration and play with the recurse option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue with eGit and Eclipse 3.7. I suggest you take a look at this Eclipse bug:

[Eclipse Bug 336612](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=336612)

I took a stack trace when my UI was freezing, and was able to match it against the stack trace in the Eclipse bug. It appeared to be an issue with how long eGit is taking to perform an operation.